# I am planning to develop a domain specific language editor, which tool is easily plugged to eclipse and use it

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I am planning to create a domain specific language editor Using Xtext. I want to know is there any tool better than xtext to develop. if yes please provide me the inputs Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming freshly from EclipseCon Europe, I seriously doubt you will find eanything better for developing DSLs in Eclipse than Xtext. It's THE technology in that context.
If you are developing a huge project, this link might be helpful, though: http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2359

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the answer from @Calon I would like to point you to the screen casts about Xtext

http://xtextcasts.org

Watch episodes 2 and 3 to get started with Xtext.